# Установка phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

Здравствуйте, у меня возник вопрос, на который, спустя полчаса гугления, я не смог найти ответа.
Установка phpMyAdmin на сервер каким-то образом меняет конфигурацию самой системы либо уже ранее установленных пакетов (например, модули php) или она просто устанавливает php-шное приложение и подключается потом к уже установленному mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зависит от способа установки.

1. Вы [скачиваете](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin) сами phpMyAdmin, копируете в нужный домен, меняете конфигурацию (именно для phpMyAdmin). 
   В данном случае никак не затрагиваете конфигурацию системы. Аналогично при установке через [`composer`](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#installing-using-composer)
2. Устанавливаете с помощью менеджера пакетов, не скажу по всем ОС, например в debian `phpMyAdmin` есть в репозитарии, можно установить с помощью `apt` или `apt-get` ([пример](https://wiki.debian.org/ru/LaMp#phpMyAdmin)). В данном случае будут установлены пакеты дополнительные, внесены изменения в конфигурацию, необходимые для работы `phpMyAdmin`
3. Вы используете какие-либо вспомогательные инсталлеры, которые возможно тоже вносят изменения в процессе установке.
4. Используете [`docker`](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#installing-using-docker). Здесь уже зависит от Вас, отдельный ли образ будет или совмещен с другими решениями Вашими.